# Need help getting rid of NaN

Tags: python

Hey I am new to python and data analytics and I was working on a project for world happiness report. I am trying to combine top 10 happiest countries and top 10 unhappiest countries but it is giving me this NaN.

[This is the variable I set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzY6m.png)

[This is the output I got on the bottom is where I keep getting NaN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXcx4.png)

Comment: For a start, extract a [mcve] and include that in your question, along with the output it produces. Both of them should be text, not links and anyone should be able to copy'n'paste your code in order to reproduce your results. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`+` will use the `__add__` operation (depending on the object type) to the operator along the axis. In case of numbers, will literally add the numbers in the same axis's. You should use `append`.

Try

`hap_and_unhap = hap.append(unhap)`

Comment: Awesome thanks so much just tried it and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `df` refers to a pandas data frame, you can try using this

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.concat([Hap, Unhap])
```